# Laravel 5.2 accessing session collection to get item value in Blade template

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a collection stored in `Session`. I am trying to access one of the keys/values inside the collection in a `Blade` template. Essentially loading a logo on a page:

My `Blade` template contains the following:

```
<img class="navbar-brand" src="@if (Session::has('organisation'))
                                   {!! env("ACC_IMAGE_PATH") . session('organisation->logo') !!}
                               @else
                                   {!! env("SI_LOGO") !!}
                               @endif"/>
```

What I am trying to access is `organisationActive->logo`, so that if an organisation is already selected that its logo will appear. The collection is of one single row / instance of Organisation.

How do I achieve this in the `Blade` template? I have tried:

```
{!! env("ACC_IMAGE_PATH") . session('organisation->logo') !!}
{!! env("ACC_IMAGE_PATH") . session('organisation.logo') !!}
```

This works in my controller and I could pass the template the value in a variable but I would rather use method injection to access the value directly from session in the `Blade` template.

```
$organisation = $request->session()->get('organisations');
dd($organisation->id);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is:

```
{!! env("ACC_IMAGE_PATH") . session('organisation')['logo'] !!}
```

Comment: side note, as of 5.2 you must only be making `env` calls from inside config files if you plan on using `artisan config:cache`

Comment: Thanks @lagbox! A whole new area of learning has just been opened for me with your comment!